# replace in word (wildcards) for multiple rows

Tags: vba, ms-word, wildcard

I want to make a search/replace macro in word which is on 2 or 3 rows, like this

```
"art. 2
2
pct. 22 din"
```

and convert it to this

```
"art. 2<sup>2</sup>
pct. 22 din"
```

instead of art. i can have other words too like lit., pct., alin. and the numbers are always different

i tried to use the next wildcard replace but it doesn't work:

```
search: "(art. )([0-9]{1;})(^13)([0-9]{1;})(^13)"
replace: "\1\2<sup>\3</sup>^p"
```

if i type only (art. )([0-9]{1;})(^13) at the search field it works, but if i type the rest it doesn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late to be helpful, but I think this will do the trick, if I odd the horrible Word syntax correctly (I used [this guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx#_Toc286834986) to check).

```
Search:  ([a-z]@. )([0-9]@)^13([0-9]@)^13
```

With your replace as before.

```
First line match: 
    ([a-z]@. )   - Any lower case letter occurring 1 or more times, followed by a dot.
    ([0-9]@)     - Any digit occurring one or more times.
    ^13          - Paragraph mark.
Second line match:
    ([0-9]@)     - Any digit occurring one or more times.
    ^13          - Paragraph mark.
```

If you find yourself doing stuff like this a lot, it might be worth using something that supports more common regular expressions (e.g. Notepad++ or similar). You might find the syntax a little bit more readable, and it would have the added bonus of teaching you something you can apply across many other environments.